# What is causing this AttributeError when fitting a classifier with tensor flow?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, tensorflow

I am trying to edit some example tensor code flow to train and test a convolutional neural network with some data. I currently have the following code which sets tensor flow things up and gets my image data from file:

```
mnist_classifier = learn.Estimator(
      model_fn=cnn_model_fn, model_dir="/tmp/mnist_convnet_model")


tensors_to_log = {"probabilities": "softmax_tensor"}
logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(
      tensors=tensors_to_log, every_n_iter=50)


testImages = []
testLabels = []
for filename in os.listdir('images'):
    im = cv2.imread('images/' + filename)
    testImages.append(im)
    testLabels.append(np.int32(1.0))

for filename in os.listdir('badImages'):
    im = cv2.imread('badImages/' + filename)
    testImages.append(im)
    testLabels.append(np.int32(0.0))
```

I then attempt to fit the model with the following line:

```
 mnist_classifier.fit(
      x=testImages,
      y=testLabels,
      batch_size=10,
      steps=20000,
      monitors=[logging_hook])
```

But this crashes at run time with the following error:

```
if x_is_dict else check_array(x, x.dtype)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

It seems like it is saying there is some problem with the structure/format of my testImages var but I have confirmed it is the right type - an numpy.ndarray of numpy.ndarrays. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says that `x` is a `list`, and thus does not have a `dtype`.  In the `fit` command I see

```
x=testImages,
```

and earlier

```
testImages = []   # and list append's
```

Where did you confirm that is is an array?

Comment: After I appended to testImages I printed the type of it and it said bumpy.ndarray, will check this out again though

Answer (score 0):

I think your `x` should be of type [numpy array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html), but it looks like you are using a list

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x= np.array([1,2,3])
>>> x.dtype
dtype('int64')
>>> y=[1,2,3]
>>> y.dtype
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```